# Touchpad disabled/No Mouse HELP

Tags: touchpad

So Im running Ubuntu 20.04 and I disabled my touchpad because i was using a mouse with a usb drive. Someone jacked my mouse and my touchpad is still disabled. What do i do please help!!!!

Comment: What did you do that disabled it?

Answer (score 1):

In "Settings" on the "Mouse & Touchpad" tab, there is a toggle to switch the touchpad on.